# Joomla subcategory article links on category page

Tags: php, joomla, categories, items

I'm using category page, and i have a list of subcategories there.
like:

Category Title
category descirption

Category Title 02
category descirption

Category Title 03
category descirption

and i wanna add a links to the articles inside those subcategories.
I know, i have to make changes in com_content/views/category/tmpl/default_children.php
but what i have to insert there?

i've found this is for the main category

```
<?php echo $this->loadTemplate('articles'); ?>
```

but what to put if i wanna have articles from child?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that if you have enough positions in your template, you can just make a custom HTML module, add your link in it, then assign it where it must be shown.

changing the main files of joomla is not recommended. besides after updates you should check if you have to change you code again?